# lb4 app throws "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, npm, loopback4

I am trying to create a loopback4 application following [the official loopback documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Getting-started.html#create-a-new-project)

- nvm version: 0.39.1
- node version: v17.4.0
- npm version: 8.3.1

I installed loopback4 using `npm i -g @loopback/cli`

I get the following error when creating a project using `lb4 app`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the node version. I was using the node version - v17.4.0 which is the current release.
I switched to the latest LTS version i.e v16.13.2 and that fixed the problem. It seems that loopback4 doesn't yet support the latest version.